# Bitbucket: disable pull requests auto-updating

Tags: git, bitbucket

I submitted a pull request in Bitbucket to merge my feature branch to develop branch `FeatureA(branch) -> develop(branch)`. After a few hours I found there is a message showed on my PR said that  `Some guy UPDATED the pull request by adding 1 commit`, but this commit is from develop branch and its commit time is before I created my feature branch.

And I didn't pull the latest change from develop branch, so it seems Bitbucket auto pull new changes from develop branch to my PR. And the problem is that it creates conflicts in my PR now.

So if Bitbucket do auto merge code into an open PR, how could I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone merged a pull request from *their* branch to 'develop' before you merged your pull request.
That's a common pattern when teams collaborate on a shared 'develop' branch.
The best way forward is to run these commands locally while you're on your feature branch

- git fetch origin develop
- git merge FETCH_HEAD
  // resolve conflicts
- git merge --continue
- git push

This way you resolve the conflicts locally and your pull request becomes a trivial merge to 'develop'.
Then make sure to merge your pull request in Bitbucket in due time.

Comment: Yeah, per my several days observation, it seems Bitbucket would merge any new changes on 'develop' branch to my Pull Request which could cause the conflicts if we change the same file for instance. And I did a rebase to include those changes, and yes merge is 1 option too.

Comment: I could be that my PR was merged quickly before so I didn't notice this behavior from Bitbucket.